# concise if statements in django templating system

Tags: django, templates

Here is the monster inefficient code:

```
{% for link in header_links %}
    {% if not link.image %}
    {% if not link.url %}
            <li><a href="{{ link|lower }}">{{ link }}</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
    {% if not link.url %}
            <li><a href="{{ link|lower }}"><img src="{{ link }}" /></a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li><a href="{{ link.url }}"><img src="{{ link.image }}" /></a></li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif%}
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see, this is ridiculous. A simple tertiary statement or two would be totally fitting, except within the {% %} blocks I can't access the variables with filters and things like that.

Here is my python/django pseduo code that expresses the same thing with the efficiency I think is possible.

```
{% for link in header_links %}
            <li><a href="{% print link|lower if not image.url else image.url %}">{% print "<img src='" + link.image + "' />" if link.image else print link %}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see, using two tertiary statements would be awesome and much more visually efficient anyway. Yet this code doesn't work.

Any suggestions would be awesome!!

Thanks,
Django Noob

IN CLOSING:

We came to the conclusion that following the MVC paradigm leads me to do the "heavy" lifting to the controller section and give the view as little thinking as possible.

The pseudo code I will end up using will be as follows:

in the view

```
header_links = {}
links = Link.object.all()
for link in links:
    header_links['url'] = (link.name if not link.url else link.url)
    header_links['name'] = (link.name if not link.image else "<img src='" + link.image +"' />")
context = Context({
"header_links": header_links
})
```

in the controller

```
{% for link in header_links %}
    <li><a href="{{ link['url']|lower }}"><img src="{{ link['name'] }}" /></a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What about doing this processing in your code, and returning the right value of 'link' ? Sometimes making the view (your template) as 'stupid' as possible is the way to go !

Comment: you are right! That is awesome! I knew I was going about this poorly! That is the mvc way! Thanks!

Comment: feel free to make that an answer and you get credit!

Comment: It's OK if you got another answer :-) It also helps to know how to do "clean" if statements, but you should always try to make your views 'dumb', It'll save you a lot of trouble ;-).

Comment: I didn't get the answer I wanted, you gave me the correct answer to my issue. But I wanted to give Paulo credit for giving me a good answer to my immediate issue. Although it is not addressing my design flaws.

Comment: @phileaton thanks. First I thought about suggesting the halflings' approach but I think this is more a design issue. Is just a consideration problem but I think that including that logic in the view will couple the view with the template, thats why I didn't suggest it after all but is a very valid choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rewrote your if statement and I think this way looks more obvious. Is not the most clever solution but It's more readable.

```
{% for link in header_links %}
    {% if not link.image  and not link.url%}
        <li><a href="{{ link|lower }}">{{ link }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if not link.image  and link.url%}
            <li><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if link.image  and not link.url%}
        <li><a href="{{ link|lower }}"><img src="{{ link }}" /></a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if link.image  and link.url%}
        <li><a href="{{ link.url }}"><img src="{{ link.image }}" /></a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
{% for link in header_links %}
    <li>
        {% if link.url and link.image %}
            <a href="{{ link.url }}"><img src="{{ link.image }}" /></a>
        {% elif not link.url %}
            <a href="{{ link|lower }}"><img src="{{ link }}" /></a>
        {% elif not link.image %}
            <a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link }}</a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{{ link|lower }}">{{ link }}</a>
        {% endif%}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```